# Automapper and Nested Object

Tags: c#, automapper

Suppose I have the following classes

```
public class Parent {
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children{get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Child {
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    // other properties
}


public class ParentVm {
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<ChildVm> Children{get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class ChildVm {
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

Parent parent = /*something*/
var parentVm = Mapper.Map<ParentVm>(parent);
```

In the `ChildVm`, there is property `ParentId`. How can I propagate that value to using automapper?

Comment: It doesn't appear by your question that you are trying to map `ChildVm`.`ParentId` to anything. Also, it appears that your `Mapper.Map` command is backward if you are trying to create a `ParentVm`, as that line will create a `Parent` object.

Is the real use case trying to map a `Parent` object, which has `Child` objects to a `ParentVm` which has `ChildVm` objects? And to have the `Parent`.`ParentId` property propagate to the `ChildVm`.`ParentId` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions with your question.

1. You are trying to map `Parent` to `ParentVm` (and `Child` to `ChildVm`).
2. You are trying to map `Parent`.`ParentId` to `ChildVm`.`ParentId`.

If both of these are true, then the following code snippet (from [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)) should help you. Note the use of `AfterMap` in the first `CreateMap`.

```
void Main()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Parent, ParentVm>().AfterMap((s, d) =>
        {
            foreach (var child in d.Children)
            {
                child.ParentId = d.ParentId;
            }
        });
        cfg.CreateMap<Child, ChildVm>();
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var parent = new Parent { ParentId = 1, Children = new List<Child>() };
    var child1 = new Child { ChildId = 1 };
    var child2 = new Child { ChildId = 2 };
    parent.Children.Add(child1);
    parent.Children.Add(child2);

    var parentVm = mapper.Map<Parent, ParentVm>(parent);
    parentVm.Dump();
}

public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    // other properties
}


public class ParentVm
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<ChildVm> Children { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class ChildVm
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

Output:

[image: LINQPad Dump Results]